# How to format and remove spaces from a certificate with php?

Tags: javascript, php, str-replace

In javascript I see something like this which gives the certificate a shape:

```
substr(certificateX509, '\n');
certificateX509 = certificateX509.substr(certificateX509.indexOf('\n'));
certificateX509 = certificateX509.substr(0, certificateX509.indexOf('\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'));
certificateX509 = certificateX509.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').replace(/([^\0]{76})/g, '$1\n');
console.log(certificateX509);
```

output:

```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```

While in php, I do the following:

```
$certificado = str_replace('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----', '', $certificado);
$certificado = str_replace('-----END CERTIFICATE-----', '', $certificado);
$certificado=trim($certificado);
$certificado = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $certificado);
```

output:

```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```

The output I get is very different, 76 characters or code of the certificate get in javascript horizontally and while in PHP 64 characters or code, how can I get the 76 in horizontally line in php?

> Note, I have shortened the code of the certificate randomly so that my question is not extensive, but here is the demo with the complete certificate: https://3v4l.org/Q3N2R#v8.1.6

Comment: It seems odd you'd need to trim it. Normally a library can load it in from the default, spaced out form. Note that the JavaScript function just restructures it to be 76 character lines. Your PHP code does not.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I know, it is really strange, but I am imitating how the data should go to validate an electronic signature and the format is in 76 characters in the certificate, will there be no problems?

Comment: Use `preg_replace()` in PHP to insert newlines after every 76 characters.

Comment: Verifying a signature by smashing around the key text is an awful way to do it. Consider loading it and dumping out the fingerprint and using that to verify. That's what they're for.

Comment: You can also use the `chunk_split()` function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php

Comment: In js you are replacing new line characters with empty character that is '', but in php you are doing something else here => `$certificado = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $certificado);`  it should be => `$certificado = str_replace("\r\n", "", $certificado);`

Comment: @tadman I'm going to try it, without formatting it to see if it validates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate string in your example is grouped into 64 characters chunks, that's why your current code keeps that length in each line. The javascript code you have uses a regular expression to break it into 76 characters chunks (you can see a 76 there in the 4th line).

You can do something similar in PHP:

```
$certificado = str_replace('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----', '', $certificado);
$certificado = str_replace('-----END CERTIFICATE-----', '', $certificado);
$certificado = str_replace(" ", "", $certificado);
$certificado = str_replace("\r\n", "", $certificado);
$certificado = preg_replace('/([^\0]{76})/', "$1\r\n", $certificado);

echo $certificado;
```

You can see the result here:
https://onlinephp.io/c/e1aa8

If you prefer, you can replace the `preg_replace` line with:

```
$certificado = chunk_split($certificado);
```